# Is it possible to assign to a tf.SymbolicTensor during graph execution?

Tags: lstm, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a `tf.function` I'm trying to execute as the training step to a `keras.layers.LSTM`. During the execution of this function, I happen to need to assign an intermediate value (computed within the `tf.function`) to one of my model's hidden states (which, as I understand, are `tf.SymbolicTensor`s when under graph execution).

When I try to assign using `my_lstm.states[0].assign()`, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Is it possible to assign to a model's variable, in graph mode?

Note: I understand that it is possible to call an LSTM while passing the desired state to the `initial_state` parameter of the call function, but for code prettiness reasons, I would prefer not to do this.